# Pointwise limit function of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, proof-verification, pointwise-convergence

> Find the pointwise limit function of:
>   $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
>       0 & |x|> 1/n \\
>       nx+1 &  x \in [-1/n, 0) \\
>       1-nx &  x \in [0, 1/n]  
>    \end{cases} $$

I think that in the limit, if we fix a certain $x$, we get that:

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & |x|> 0 \\
      \infty &  x \in [0, 0) \\
      -\infty &  x \in [0, 0]  
   \end{cases} $$
 Where the second line is an empty statement, we rewrite this to:
$$\lim _{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & |x|> 0 \\
      -\infty &  x =0 
   \end{cases} $$
Did I do this correctly? I'm not sure what the formal argument should be to get rid of the half-open interval $[0,0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not correct. If $x=0$ then $f_n(x)=1$ for all $n$ and the limit is $1$. If $x \neq 0$ then  $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large so the limit is $0$.

Comment: yes that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Your notations are odd. The conclusion that the limit be zero if $x$ is nonzero is correct. (But why would you write $|x|>0$ instead of $x\neq 0$?) 
But at zero, the limit is $1$. Just check that all functions have value $1$ at zero.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x\neq 0$. Then there is an $n_0$ such that $|x|>1/n \hspace{0.3cm}\forall n\geq n_0 $: thus $f_n(x)=0$ definitively, and the pointwise limit is 0.

You are left only with $x=0$, but $f_n(0)=1 \hspace{0.2cm}\forall n$.